# refresh an element in react every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have a component that has an array of images in it and I need it to change the image after completion of an animation in css. The trumpImage component selects a random image from an array but only does it once upon loading the page. So I need it to reload the div so the image will change after completion of the animation.

```
export function Anibox() {   
    return (
            <div id="anibox">
                <span id="aniBall">{ trumpImage() }</span>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: No you don't, because reloading HTML elements is not how React works. Use a state value for that image, and then add a useEffect that starts an interval with code that updates that state value every 10 seconds. React will see the state update, and automatically rerender only those parts of the component's DOM that actually changed.

Comment: cool thank you. I just took my first javascript course and am new to react to the effect of maybe two months so i am still a noob but i got it. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

export function Anibox() {
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
  }, 10000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

return (
    
        <div id="anibox"> { seconds }
            <span id="aniBall">{ trumpImage() }</span>
        </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Please remember to read [how to post an answer](/help/how-to-answer). An explanation of what you did, and proper code formatting still matters. That said: this is not a great solution, as "set seconds" does nothing. Instead, that _image_ is your state, so you use `const [image, setImage] = useState(trumpImage());` and then inside your interval, you call `setImage(trumpImage())`, using `{ image }` in your span.